# How to use --replay-blockchain on stopped EOS 'nodeos' container

Tags: nodeos

Setup local Docker EOS "nodeos" container. Process running fine.

```
docker run \
--name nodeos -d -p 8888:8888 \
--network eosdev \
-v /tmp/eosio/work:/work \
-v /tmp/eosio/data:/mnt/dev/data \
-v /tmp/eosio/config:/mnt/dev/config \
eosio/eos-dev \
/bin/bash -c \
"nodeos -e -p eosio \
--plugin eosio::producer_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_plugin \
--plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::http_plugin \
-d /mnt/dev/data \
--config-dir /mnt/dev/config \
--http-server-address=0.0.0.0:8888 \
--access-control-allow-origin=* \
--contracts-console \
--http-validate-host=false"
```

Container is created and running fine.

I want to replay the blockchain as changed the config in the container.

Having difficulty to use `--replay-blockchain with docker start <container_id>` command because container is already created and I do not want to re-create the container but still want to replay the blockchain.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

If you posted the error, it would help.

You may need to hard replay:

```
docker run \
  --name nodeos -d -p 8888:8888 \
  --network eosdev \
  -v /tmp/eosio/work:/work \
  -v /tmp/eosio/data:/mnt/dev/data \
  -v /tmp/eosio/config:/mnt/dev/config \
  eosio/eos-dev \
/bin/bash -c \
  "nodeos -e -p eosio \
    --plugin eosio::producer_plugin \
    --plugin eosio::history_plugin \
    --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
    --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin \
    --plugin eosio::http_plugin \
    -d /mnt/dev/data \
    --config-dir /mnt/dev/config \
    --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:8888 \
    --access-control-allow-origin=* \
    --contracts-console \
    --http-validate-host=false
    --hard-replay-blockchain"
```

If hard replay does not work, you may need to delete all blocks.

See differences:

```
  --replay-blockchain                   clear chain state database and replay
                                        all blocks
  --hard-replay-blockchain              clear chain state database, recover as
                                        many blocks as possible from the block
                                        log, and then replay those blocks
  --delete-all-blocks                   clear chain state database and block
                                        log
```

Comment: Thats helps, my issues is, I already have container created which I created without above flags. Now I want to use --reply-blockchain flag. I guess it more docker related then EOS

Comment: You can just use the docker command I provided, it has the replay command at the end.

Comment: You need to understand, your docker command will create a new container. I know this solution. I want to reply the blockchain which is already running in existing container.

Comment: Ah I see.  According to the docker docs, you would run `docker stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]` or `docker stop nodeos` to stop running the container.  This is also how docker is handled in https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio-project-demux-example `docker stop eosio_blog_container`.  To restart, the demux example says to run `docker run --rm --name [CONTAINER] -d...`, you can see here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio-project-demux-example/blob/master/start_eosio_docker.sh